# Add Second Times to Database Without Refresh Page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I use the following code to stop the page refreshing problem. This code  only inserts data in to the database the first time. When I want to insert a second time I must refresh the page. Please help

below is form that user can inter some info into textbox

```html
    form  method='Get' action="insert.php"  id='myform' >
    <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description">
    <input type="text" name="Unitys" id="Unitys">
    <input type="text" name="quantitys" id="quantitys">
    <input type="text" name="Text1s" id="Text1s">
    
    <input type="text" name="PurchaseQty" id="PurchaseQty">
    <input type="text" name="Amount1" id="Amount1">
    
    <input class="button is-info is-large" id="btn_save" name="btn_save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="myFunctions();reflash()" />
    <p id='result'></p>           
    
    </form>
```

this code below is to stop page refreshing after click the button

```js
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn_save').click(function(){
    var data=$('#myform').serialize()+'&btn_save=btn_save';
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type:'Get',
        data:data,
        success:function(response){
        $('#result').text(response);
    $('#Description').text('');
    $('#Unitys').text('');
    $('#quantitys').text('');
    $('#Text1s').text('');
  $('#PurchaseQty').text('');
  $('#Amount1').text('');
        }
    });
});
});

</script>
```

This below is insert to php another

```php
    if (isset($_GET['btn_save'])){
    
    $DescriptionZ =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['Description']);
    $UnityZ = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['Unitys']);
    $quantityZ =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['quantitys']);
    $TextZ = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['Text1s']);
    $PurchaseQtyZ = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['PurchaseQty']);
    $AmountZ= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['Amount1']);
    
    
    $sql= "INSERT INTO `orders`(`id`, `OrderID`, `Description`, `Unit`, `Quantity`, `Cost`, `Purchasing Qty`, `Amount`) 
    VALUES (NULL,'[555]','$DescriptionZ','$UnityZ','$quantityZ','$TextZ','$PurchaseQtyZ','$AmountZ')";
      $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
      if($query)
      {
          echo "Data Saved Successfully";
          
      } else {
          echo "Failed to save data";
      }
    }

<!--end of insert.php-->
```

Comment: This code alone does not explain why that would be a problem. Please build a [mre] of your issue and then [edit] your question to include it. Then we can help you properly. Thanks.

Comment: try refresh your page on background

Comment: Assuming your `#btn_save` element is a submit button, then you're not preventing the page from being refreshed. Although that wouldn't cause the issue you describe. More detail is needed here in order for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, why are you using a GET if you have to insert data into the DB?
Anyway try something like that:

```
$('#btn_save').click(function() {
var data = $('#myform').serialize() + '&btn_save=btn_save';
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: 'Get',
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#result').text(response);
    $('#Description').text('');
    $('#Unitys').text('');
    $('#quantitys').text('');
    $('#Text1s').text('');
    $('#PurchaseQty').text('');
    $('#Amount1').text('');
  }
});
```

Extract it from the: `$(document).ready()`

Comment: post or get their giving me same result thanks for code but i got same problem i edited my code